# Using custom layouts in Social Engine?

Tags: css, themes, socialengine

Is is possible to use custom layout in Social Engine?
I haven't found any tutorial how to do this.
Is it true I can only edit css for theme?

Answer (score 4):

According to this:

http://www.socialengine.net/support/documentation/article?q=145&question=Customize-Your-Site-HeaderFooter

creating / customizing theme happens by CSS modification. There is information about 2 files that can be modified, and both of them are CSS files.

But, in fact, **CSS is very powerful and you can significantly change outlook (even layout)** of the page. Maybe you do not need to modify any other files?

Answer (score 0):

Really, according to this:
http://support.socialengine.com/questions/145/Customize-Your-Site-Header-Footer
you are advised to modify only css style files. But you can edit /application/modules/Core/layouts/scripts/default.tpl considering that eventually these changes will be overwritten after an update.